# Props "undefined" within useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I've been using a user ID token, in the form of a props that I get from my database on login and store in the Redux store. So far so good, it works everywhere in my app EXCEPT when I try to retrieve it at page load in a useEffect :

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const findLang = async () => {
     const raw = await fetch(`/user-lang?token=${props.token}`);
     const data = await raw.json();
     setLanguage(data.lang)
  };
   findLang();
  }, []);
```

All I get is an `undefined`, and my whole component depends on this token. However, it is available in the component outside of the useEffect function, so it's something that has to do with the useEffect. Can anyone think of a way to bypass this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application redux store is initialized, the token doesn't exist yet. The `useEffect()` block needs to be called when token changes, and skip the `findLang()` call if `token` doesn't exist yet:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!props.token) return; // if token doesn't exist yet, don't call the api

  const findLang = async() => {
    const raw = await fetch(`/user-lang?token=${props.token}`);
    const data = await raw.json();
    setLanguage(data.lang)
  };
  findLang();
}, [props.token]);
```

If you don't want `useEffect()` to react to `token` changes after the 1st time you update it, you can use ref to avoid it:

```
const langFetched = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!props.token || langFetched.current) return; // if token doesn't exist yet lang already fetched, don't call the api

  langFetched.current = true;

  const findLang = async() => {
    const raw = await fetch(`/user-lang?token=${props.token}`);
    const data = await raw.json();
    setLanguage(data.lang)
  };
  findLang();
}, [props.token]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The thing is, I can't do without `token`, it's the basis of my functionality. Without it, the thing falls apart. So telling the browser to carry on without `token` with if(!props.token) is not an option, it is required to load language-specific info on page load. I guess I'm just gonna have to remove this functionality from my website :/

Comment: You don't actually have to remove it. The app would just need to adapt. For example, display a spinner instead of rendering the app until the token is available.